# Argument "mainPanel" is missing with no default in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm fairly new to Shiny R! I think I might be missing a parentheses but I kept checking and I couldn't find the error. Sorry for posting such a big amount of code! But is it possible if you guys can check where I might be missing a parentheses?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "Demo Bar",
             tabPanel("Percent college",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput(inputId = "state", label = "Select a state:",
                                      choices = unique(midwest$state),
                                      selected = "IL",
                                      multiple = TRUE),
                          hr(),
                          helpText("Data From Midwest data frame"),
                          textInput(inputId = "title", label = "Write a title!", value = "Midwest scatter plot comparison"),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotlyOutput("scatterplot")
                      ),
             ),
             ),
             tabPanel("Data Page",
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    sliderInput(
                      inputId = "area_choice",
                      label = "Range of Area",
                      min = area_range[1],
                      max = area_range[2],
                      value = area_range
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      plotOutput("plot")
                  ),
                ),
             ),
             ),
),
)
```

Comment: Your last `mainPanel` is inside `sidebarPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

1. As commented by Stephane, your `mainPanel` was misplaced
2. You had a few commas without further input which can be problematic in R

Also note I had to add `area_range` and the `library` calls. Your example was not directly reproducible

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
area_range <- c(1,2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "Demo Bar",
             tabPanel("Percent college",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput(inputId = "state", label = "Select a state:",
                                      choices = unique(midwest$state),
                                      selected = "IL",
                                      multiple = TRUE),
                          hr(),
                          helpText("Data From Midwest data frame"),
                          textInput(inputId = "title", label = "Write a title!", value = "Midwest scatter plot comparison"),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotlyOutput("scatterplot")
                        )
                      )
             ),
             tabPanel("Data Page",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput(
                            inputId = "area_choice",
                            label = "Range of Area",
                            min = area_range[1],
                            max = area_range[2],
                            value = area_range
                          ),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {})
```